# Moving an object in mfc

Tags: mfc, onmousemove

I am trying to move an ellipse that I created to another position. Previously I checked if the mouse is over ellipse and change the colour of the ellipse. Now I am having a problem with moving the ellipse that I made. Here is my code of Buttondown event handler

```cpp
CClientDC dc(this);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    dc.SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);
    dc.SetWindowExt(100, 100);
    dc.SetViewportExt(rect.Width(), rect.Height());



    //CRect rectEllipse = new CRect(0, 0, 12, 7);
    CRect rectEllipse(ellipse.cx, ellipse.cy, (ellipse.cx) + 12, (ellipse.cy) + 7);
    CRgn elipseRgn;


    elipseRgn.CreateEllipticRgnIndirect(rectEllipse);

    if (elipseRgn.RectInRegion(&rectEllipse))
    {
        SetCapture();
        mouseCapture = true;
        dc.DPtoLP(&point);

        if (elipseRgn.PtInRegion(point)) 
        {
            CBrush myBrush;
            myBrush.CreateHatchBrush(HS_CROSS, RGB(0, 0, 255));
            dc.SelectObject(myBrush);
            dc.Ellipse(ellipse.cx, ellipse.cy, (ellipse.cx) + 12, (ellipse.cy) + 7);
            InvalidateRect(rectEllipse, FALSE);
        }

    }



    CDialogEx::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

and this is my code for OnMouseMove event handler:

```cpp
CRect rectEllipse(ellipse.cx, ellipse.cy, (ellipse.cx) + 12, (ellipse.cy) + 7);
if (mouseCapture)
{
    InvalidateRect(rectEllipse, TRUE);
    ellipse.cx = point.x;
    ellipse.cy = point.y;
    CRect rectNew(ellipse.cx, ellipse.cy, (ellipse.cx) + 12, (ellipse.cy) + 7);
    InvalidateRect(rectNew, TRUE);
}
```

Every time I run the code and try to move this ellipse all that happens when the left mouse button is pressed over the ellipse is the ellipse is erased in the location where the mouse is pressed. I need to move this ellipse across the screen with mouse botton pressed down over the ellipse and to keep the new colour. Can someone help me resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: The painting should happen only in your OnPaint method. Create a member variable for the CRect variable that represents the current position of the ellipse and perform the whole drawing there

Comment: Check **DrawCli** sample available on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you guys. Yes the problem was I did not redraw a new ellipse in OnPaint().

Comment: I Have another question. After doing all of this, I have to move this ellipse around the box and when I touch on of two rectangles that I made, Rectangle has to change colour to red and display msg in the centre of that rectangle. I know for that I have to use member function of Crgn but every time I try that when I execute program it says that there is an error?! This is my OnMouse Move event: